# owerride function in keil

Tags: c, keil

I used printf for serial print by this function:

```
struct __FILE { int handle;} ;
//FILE __stdout;
//FILE __stdin;
//FILE __stderr;

int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
{ 
    while(!USART_GetFlagStatus(COM3,USART_FLAG_TXE));
    USART_SendData(COM3,ch);
    return ch;
}
```

This worked but when I want to create a file and write on it with fwrite function, data send to serial!! How can I tell to micro fwrite don't use my fputc function and write data to file not serial?
When I remove my fputc function, data write to file but I want to use printf for debug and I don't want to remove it.

I hope I've been able to figure out what I mean.

Regards,
Alireza

I change it to:

```
#define WriteToUART3    0
#define WriteToFile     1

int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)  
{
    int ret = EOF;
    switch( f->handle )
    {
        case WriteToUART3 :
            while(!USART_GetFlagStatus(COM3,USART_FLAG_TXE));         
            USART_SendData(COM3,ch);
            ret = ch ;
            break ;
        case WriteToFile :
            ????????
            ret = ch ;
            break ;
        default :
        break ;
    }
    return ret ; 
}
```

What I must write instead of ???????? ?!
Thanks

Comment: You need to make `fputc` detect what kind of stream you're using. Your solution could be similar to [Using printf with two UARTs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476314/using-printf-with-two-uarts)

Comment: Thanks,I change my post.But I don't know what I must write instead of ?????? now.I know that I must call original fputc function, but how?!

Comment: Can you actually write to a file? What library are you using for file io?

Comment: Yes,if I remove my fputc function and use fwrite function from stdio.h library can write to file.(I think fwrite use fputs)